# Как вывести на экран запущенный через nohup процесс?

Tags: python, linux

Есть python скрипт запущенный через nohup в фоновом режиме, как мне вывести выводимый им результат в консоль?

Comment: `tail -f nohup.out` не устроит?

Comment: устроит. Спасибо